# Get saslauthd to use a Kerberos principal other than one based on the hostname

Tags: kerberos, saslauthd

We are using `saslauthd` on a Debian stretch Linux environment. We use `saslauthd` to do GSSAPI (i.e., kerberos) authentications. I see that `saslauthd` uses the principal `host/<servername>` when doing Kerberos authentications where `servername` is the hostname of the server.

For various reasons we would like `saslauthd` to use a *different* Kerberos principal than `host/<servername>` when doing its authentications.

Is this possible and (if so) how?

Comment: What is calling saslauthd for auth?

Comment: OpenLDAP is calling saslauthd.